# DWG/DXF conversion to DEM file

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, dwg

I have got a detailed CAD drawing (DWG format) showing a house plan and topographic survey. I want to use the heights from the topo survey to create a digital elevation map in QGIS.

I have tried a couple of converters such as DXFtoXYZ however cannot seem to work out how to create the DEM from this.

Does anyone have any suggestions/know how to create a DEM from DWG points?

Comment: If you have a CAD application, are you not able to directly export your points to XYZs? Or if you have the XYZs already... gdal_rasterize...in the QGIS Processing toolbox should work.